# C# WPF How to check if mouse is over DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, mousemove

I'm trying to make drag and drop function on the datagrid rows and I used the MouseMove event handler on datagrid columns. But now I can't click on the combo box anymore. I was thinking about performing a check to see if the mouse is over the combo box column and exit the function if it is. But I dont know how to do this. The sender is only type DataGrid and I cant use it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may determine the underlying type of a column via `MouseMove` or `PreviewMouseMove` events as such:

```
private void DataGrid_OnPreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;

    var inputElement = dataGrid.InputHitTest(e.GetPosition(dataGrid)); // Get the element under mouse pointer

    var cell = ((Visual)inputElement).GetAncestorOfType<DataGridCell>(); // Get the parent DataGridCell element

    if (cell == null)
        return; // Only interested in cells

    var column = cell.Column; // Simple...

    if (column is DataGridComboBoxColumn comboColumn)
        ; // This is a combo box column
}
```

You'll notice I am using an interesting extension here. This is the source:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a first ancestor of the provided type.
/// </summary>
public static Visual GetAncestorOfType(this Visual element, Type type)
{
    if (element == null)
        return null;

    if (type == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(type));

    (element as FrameworkElement)?.ApplyTemplate();

    if (!(VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) is Visual parent))
        return null;

    return type.IsInstanceOfType(parent) ? parent : GetAncestorOfType(parent, type);
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns a first ancestor of the provided type.
/// </summary>
public static T GetAncestorOfType<T>(this Visual element)
    where T : Visual => GetAncestorOfType(element, typeof(T)) as T;
```

It is one of many approaches in getting the parent/ancestor element from the visual tree, I use it all the time for tasks such as the one you are facing.

You will find that `InputHitTest` method and the above extension are invaluable assets in your Drag/Drop routines.